# How to create a user in drupal

Tags: drupal

How by program to create a user after the form is submitted ?
How to preview the form before submit ?
Where in the are stored?

Comment: This question is not nearly specific enough and makes very little sense.

Comment: Yes, too many unrelated questions. About programmatically creating users look here: http://www.michaelphipps.com/how-create-users-programmatically-drupal-6x

Comment: I think this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers?referrer=LXdsV4_A0CCWm0SjsRBE2g2 would help things out a bit!

Answer (score 2):

Users are stored in the users table.

Use the Drupal API to add users.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_save/6

Users are also created in the admin for the users section. It is not a good idea to make your own form to create users, as the functionality already exists.